# I created a ResNet model but loss doesn't go down on training

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am new to deep learning and computer vision, and following completion of a Courseera course on CNN I thought of replicating the assignments but using PyTorch instead of Tensorflow. One of the assignments involved Hand Signs classification using ResNet architecture.

I created ResNet34 & ResNet50 to my best understanding of description in paper however, when I train it the loss doesn't go anywhere. It has been 3 days and I couldn't think of any fixes. Not sure at this point if it is the model or any script issue. Please refer the code on [github](https://github.com/jatinkatyal/DeepLearning/blob/main/FingerSigns/FingerSignMultiClassClassificationResNet34.ipynb).

Here is how I am creating the model and training it.

```
class Block34(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,in_c,out_c):
        super().__init__()
        
        if in_c != out_c:
            s = 2
            self.residual = True
            self.conv_s = nn.Conv2d(in_c,out_c,1,stride=s)
            self.bn_s = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_c)
        else:
            s = 1
            self.residual = False
        
        self.conv_a = nn.Conv2d(in_c,out_c,3,stride=s,padding=1)
        self.bn_a = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_c)
        self.conv_b = nn.Conv2d(out_c,out_c,3,padding=1)
        self.bn_b = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_c)
        
    def forward(self,x):
        shortcut=x
        
        out = F.relu(self.bn_a(self.conv_a(x)))
        out = self.bn_a(self.conv_a(x))
        
        if self.residual:
            shortcut = self.bn_s(self.conv_s(shortcut))
        return F.relu(out + shortcut)
```

```
class ResNet34(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3,64,7,stride=2)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(3,2)
        
        self.conv2_1 = Block34(64,64)
        self.conv2_2 = Block34(64,64)
        self.conv2_3 = Block34(64,64)
        
        self.conv3_1 = Block34(64,128)
        self.conv3_2 = Block34(128,128)
        self.conv3_3 = Block34(128,128)
        self.conv3_4 = Block34(128,128)
        
        self.conv4_1 = Block34(128,256)
        self.conv4_2 = Block34(256,256)
        self.conv4_3 = Block34(256,256)
        self.conv4_4 = Block34(256,256)
        self.conv4_5 = Block34(256,256)
        self.conv4_6 = Block34(256,256)
        
        self.conv5_1 = Block34(256,512)
        self.conv5_2 = Block34(512,512)
        self.conv5_3 = Block34(512,512)
        self.pool5 = nn.AvgPool2d(2,2)
        
        self.fc6 = nn.Linear(512,6)
    
    def forward(self, X):
        out = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(X)))
        out = self.pool1(out)
        
        out = self.conv2_1(out)
        out = self.conv2_2(out)
        out = self.conv2_3(out)
        
        out = self.conv3_1(out)
        out = self.conv3_2(out)
        out = self.conv3_3(out)
        out = self.conv3_4(out)
        
        out = self.conv4_1(out)
        out = self.conv4_2(out)
        out = self.conv4_3(out)
        out = self.conv4_4(out)
        out = self.conv4_5(out)
        out = self.conv4_6(out)
        
        out = self.conv5_1(out)
        out = self.conv5_2(out)
        out = self.conv5_3(out)
        out = self.pool5(out)
        
        c,h = out.shape[1], out.shape[2]
        out = self.fc6(out.view(-1,c*h*h))
        return F.softmax(out)
```

I am training 1080 images of shape (64,64,3) by dividing into 54 batches of 20 images each. In loops i is for epochs to train and j is for getting images of minibatch.

```
torch.manual_seed(1)
classifier = ResNet34().to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(classifier.parameters(), lr=0.75)
loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
losses = []

epochs = 10
mini_batches = int(m_train/20)
print('{} minibatches for {} epochs.'.format(mini_batches,epochs))
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(mini_batches):
        y_h = classifier(train_x[j*20:(j+1)*20].view(-1,c,h,w))
        classifier.zero_grad()
        loss = loss_func(y_h,train_y[j*20:(j+1)*20].long())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    losses.append(loss)
    print('Epoch:{}, loss:{}'.format(i,loss))
```

Output:

```
54.0 minibatches for 10 epochs.
Epoch:0, loss:1.8435920476913452
Epoch:1, loss:1.8435920476913452
Epoch:2, loss:1.8435920476913452
Epoch:3, loss:1.8435920476913452
Epoch:4, loss:1.8435920476913452
Epoch:5, loss:1.8435920476913452
Epoch:6, loss:1.8435920476913452
Epoch:7, loss:1.8435920476913452
Epoch:8, loss:1.8435920476913452
Epoch:9, loss:1.8435920476913452
```

Comment: your learning rate is astronomical. try 3e-4.
This is just one problem i noticed in your algorithm. Training a deep learning model is a complex process that required overcoming many hurdles.
if you want more help, report the resualts of this change and check back for more guidance.

Comment: @yanziselman, thanks for commenting. I used 0.0001 earlier but achieved same output however going down further actually showed a dip before convergence. 0.00001 converged in 5 epochs with 99 train and 75 test accuracy. Am I calculating the loss right?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @yanziselman for your comment on learning rate, it worked as a charm after. I am closing this question now.

So, I was using a very high Learning Rate which was causing the loss function to bounce around and reducing it showed drop in loss and finally converge.

I need to do more study :P

Comment: Happy to help, good luck on your studies.